# Safety of Tomato Sauce that pops

Tags: sauce, marinara

my tomato sauce that I keep in the fridge has been getting pressurized and will pop when I open it. It is so forceful that it splurts a little. The air inside is white but dissipates quickly after I open the jar. It just happened a second time.

Is it still safe to eat? What is going on?

More info:
I'm not sure what the fridge temperature is but I have bought the exact same brand and had it be fine the entire lifespan of the product. It is entirely possible I accidentally used a spoon to pull out some sauce that was used for something else.

Comment: Is there any metal in contact with the sauce?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should not happen, and sounds like you have some fermentation happening in the jar.  I would suggest discarding.  In the future, use only clean utensils to reach into the freshly opened jar.  Refrigerate immediately after use, and use within about a week.

Answer (score 1):

The dissipating white gas from the jar may be carbon dioxide undergoing a rapid pressure decrease, similar to opening cans/bottles of soda/beer.

If it is carbon dioxide gas build-up, your tomato sauce might be undergoing fermentation in your fridge. Can we get more context?

-Is the sauce home-made? If so, ingredients and heating steps? Added acid?

-If it's a store-bought sauce, was there any accidental contamination, i.e. bread crumbs falling in? Double-dipping utensils?

-What is your fridge air temperature?

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you have questions you should put them as comments to the question, not in an answer.